# В чем разница типов BOOL и bool?

Tags: c++, типы-данных

В чём разница типов `BOOL` и `bool`?

`BOOL` встречал [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya).

Даже если `BOOL` есть макросом определённым через `typedef`, какой в нём смысл? Так как функции в доках являются командами. По сути проверка идёт через `true` или `false`, прошло или не прошло.

Comment: bool - фундаментальный тип, std::Boolean - концепт, ещё не включённый в стандарт, BOOL - скорее всего, WinAPI макрос/typedef, не включенный в стандарт

Comment: И что-то мне подсказывает, что речь не про `std::Boolean`, а тоже про какой-то макрос/typedef из какой-то библиотеки.

Comment: Может быть. Предлагаю автору привести контексты, в которых используются эти идентификаторы, чтобы можно было дать однозначный ответ

Comment: @cppquestions, BOOL  я встречал здесь https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya

Comment: @AwesomeMan укажите все подробности в самом вопросе с помощью кнопки "[править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/934302/edit)" (заодно поднимите вопрос на главной)

Comment: BOOL winapi `TRUE = 255, FALSE = 0`, bool `из stdbool.h C true = 1, false = 0`, std:Boolean - значения аналогичные как и в случае с декларацией stdbool.h

Comment: ТС : `Посути проверка идёт через true or false, прошло или не прошло.` - в том то и дело, что значение у разных типов булов разные, но их можно все обобщить через условие, например `if (!(int)boolvalue) { // this is false }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BOOL` - это WinAPI тип, точнее, синоним, заданный через `typedef` для целого:

```
typedef int BOOL;
```

Такой синоним был заведён по причине того, что WinAPI базируется на языке C, где булевского типа нет, но отражать смысл параметра или возвращаемого значения функции хотелось бы именно как булев тип. Тем не менее из-за простого использования синонима в переменную типа `BOOL` можно записать любое значение, подходящее для типа `int`.

`bool` - это стандартный базовый тип в языке C++ для задания булева значения. В отличие от винапишного `BOOL`, может содержать только два возможных варианта: `true` или `false`.

В современном C (C11) тем не менее имеется встроенный булев тип `_Bool`, но если хочется использовать написание как в C++, нужно включить заголовочный файл `<stdbool.h>`.